# UPDATE nested array field BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, nested, sql-update

I have two table Order and Person, where i am trying to update name in Order  table from Person table by matching id.
Could anyone help on to frame the update query.

Tables

[Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lKeQ.png)

[Person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmMOA.png)

Comment: Hello, please, add the schema for the tables. Also, it will help if you post your tables with data directly in the question instead of links to pictures :)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `projectID.dataset.order` o
SET o.product.items.customer.name = 
(SELECT name FROM `projectID.dataset.person` p
WHERE o.product.items.customer.id = p.id )
WHERE  TRUE;
```

Comment: Getting below error, since the structure is defined as Array.


Error : Cannot access field artists on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<uri STRING, type STRING, total_tracks INT64, ...>> at [5:18]

Comment: Can you please provide the schema of both tables it will help me to understand the error.